# Knockout template document.ready fires before child page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

we are usign knockout template for binding multiple pages. And On the main page we have a `docuemnt.ready` event 
 `$(document).ready(function() { //some logic that makes use of the elements of child page. });`. 
 Main page holds 3 child pages and as soon as the main page loads the `ready` event executes and result with error becuase child pages were not loaded by that time.

 **So it fires error that `#inputbutton` is null or not defined. Becuase at the time when ready event executed these child pages were loading.**

So is there any way that we can hold the document.ready event of main to page to be fired after all the child page has been loaded completly? If we are able to do so then we will never get that error as every element will be available while the ready event fires.

**Sorry cant disclose code because of some reasons**

Comment: if you are using knockout template binding, then there are callbacks methods like`afterRender`, `afterAdd` and `beforeRemove` [Read here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

Comment: I don't quite understand your html creation logic but you can check out the component bindings for reusable chunks instead of templates, [here is the official documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) and cheks this [post on knockmeout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html)

Comment: @Dandy : Yes, We have to make use of callbacks. I found this helpful. Thank You :)

Comment: If you find a viable solution to your problem maybe you should answer your own question for other users that may  run across your question on their searches